# Make <img> use cached result in multiple instances of Angular component

Tags: html, angular

I have an Angular component called folder-browser which serves as a folder browser. It displays the folders in a vertical list, and when a folder is opened it displays folders within that folder if there are any:

[image]

Here is the HTML for this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let element of folders">
    <div class="folder" (click)="selectFolder(element)" [ngClass]="{'selected': checkSelected(element)}">
        <div class="chevron-container">
            <img class="chevron-icon" src="{{getChevronIcon(element)}}">
        </div>
        <img class="folder-icon" src="{{folderIcon}}" />
        <span class="folder-name">{{element.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-folders" *ngIf="element.expanded">
        <folder-browser [folders]="element.children"></folder-browser>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is about the two `<img>` elements (there are three distinct SVGs—the chevron img element uses either a down chevron or a right chevron). As you can see, these img elements are used many times; not only are they inside an `*ngFor` div, this folder-browser component is used recursively to display subfolders.

The src of these img elements points to a CDN. Looking at the network tab of Chrome dev tools, I can see that each folder-browser component that is initialized makes three calls to the CDN for the three image types. Additionally, every time a folder is opened and closed (which switches the chevron between facing down and right), the down and right chevron SVGs are loaded from the CDN.

Since there are only three different SVGs being used, I would like the browser to only load each one once and then use the cached image for each subsequent img element. This seems to happen to some extent, since only one request is made per image type when the component is initialized as opposed to however many folders are in the *ngIf. However, when initializing a new instance of the same component it would be nice if it would use the cached images since they are the same.

Is there a built-in way to do this?

Comment: You can include SVGs right into your project for example...

Comment: Yes I know but we are using a microservices architecture and we'd prefer to keep shared static resources on the CDN rather than duplicating them across container instances.